# Consider a linear oscillator with linear friction:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + c\frac{dx}{dt} + kx = 0$$

is the DE that governs motion. $C$ & $k$ positive

I need to show

$$E = \frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{k}2x^2$$

is a decreasing function of time.

Also, need to show that if $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$ then $$\frac{dv}{dx} = -\frac{cv+kx}{mv}$$.

Any thoughts/ ideas welcome.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Calculate $dE/dt$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets show $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ with $a$ and $\frac{d x}{dt}$ with $v$.

The main equation is

$$ma+cv+kx=0$$

and

$$E=\frac12mv^2+\frac12kx^2$$

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=mva+kxv=v(ma+kx)=v(0-cv)=-cv^2<0$$

second part:

$$ma=-(cv+kx)$$

$$a=-\frac{cv+kx}{m}$$

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dv}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{a}{v}=-\frac{cv+kx}{mv}$$

Answer (score 0):

you can write the second order differential equation as a system of two first order equations in the following way(there are many ways this can be done):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = v, \, \frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{kx +cv}{m}.$$ from these, eliminating $t,$ you can get $$\frac{dv}{dx} = -\frac{kx+cv}{mv}$$ which can be rearranged as 
$$d\left(\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2\right) = -cv\, dx= -c\,dt $$ that is $$\frac{dE}{dt} = -c, \text{ where } E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2. $$